# Restore database by files from broken Ubuntu server

Tags: mysql, ubuntu-12.04, innodb, restore

I'm pretty lost right now.

The RAID controller auf my server broke and all attached hard drives were corrupted. Luckily I copied the plain files off the server right before the crash (phew).

I set up the new server with Ubuntu 12.04 and a fresh mysql installation. I copied the backup off a server directly to the new one, without saving them to a windows machine (to prevent privileges errors).

My back up folder looks like this:

```
drwx------ 15 jensma jensma 4.0K Dec 12 18:09 .
drwxr-xr-x 76 jensma jensma 4.0K Nov 22 12:00 ..
drwx------  2 mysql  mysql  4.0K Nov 21 02:50 gamefilesenter code here
drwx------  2 mysql  mysql  4.0K Aug  5 00:17 circuitboard
-rw-r--r--  1 mysql  mysql     0 Oct 25 07:49 debian-5.5.flag
-rw-rw----  1 mysql  mysql   26M Dec 12 02:22 ibdata1
-rw-rw----  1 mysql  mysql  5.0M Dec 12 18:09 ib_logfile0
-rw-rw----  1 mysql  mysql  5.0M Dec 12 02:22 ib_logfile1
drwx------  2 mysql  mysql  4.0K Oct 25 07:49 mysql
-rw-rw----  1 mysql  mysql     6 Oct 25 07:49 mysql_upgrade_info
drwx------  2 mysql  mysql  4.0K Oct 25 07:49 performance_schema
drwx------  2 mysql  mysql  4.0K May 25  2013 phpmyadmin
drwx------  2 mysql  mysql  4.0K Jul  4 18:29 test
drwx------  2 mysql  mysql  4.0K May 19  2013 usr_web10_5
```

A folder contains data like this:

```
drwx------  2 mysql  mysql  4096 Aug  5 00:17 .
drwx------ 15 jensma jensma 4096 Dec 12 18:09 ..
-rw-rw----  1 mysql  mysql    65 Jul 10 15:04 db.opt
-rw-rw----  1 mysql  mysql  8620 Aug  1 23:38 stat.frm
-rw-rw----  1 mysql  mysql  8700 Aug  5 00:17 user.frm
```

I just copied the whole content to /var/lib/mysql and ran

```
sudo /usr/sbin/mysqld –innodb_log_file_size=5242880 –innodb_force_recovery=6
```

Well, the command kinda works - the shell shows up after half a minute. But the database is still empty :/

I'm pretty now to this. I do have full admin access to the server.

Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  While your question is well-written and presented it is off-topic for this site - see http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic.  You will probably fare better by moving it to serverfault.com

Comment: Thanks, gonna try it there, too!